# Angular NgFor always shoes the last value from the entered object

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ngfor

I have this markup:

```
<div *ngFor="let quantity of model.quantities">
                            <div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Quantity:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.name" name="quantityname" placeholder="Enter Quantity" type="text">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Price:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.price" name="quantityprice" placeholder="Enter Price" type="text">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
```

Every time I'm adding a new object of type quantity in the model, for each object in the array the same value is set, the one which is entered as last https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqQ1Fbt4zL

This is the button click event:

```
addNewQuantity() {
        if (this.newQuantity) {
            let quantity = new PriceGridQuantity();
            quantity.name = this.newQuantity;
            this.model.quantities.push(quantity);
            this.newQuantity = '';
        }   
    }
```

Update: 
model added:

```
model: any = {
        TenantId: '',
        CustomFieldName: '',
        quantities: []
    };
```

Comment: To the person who voted for closing the question, please check the video and you'll see what I'm asking thx

Comment: can I see the code declaration for model.quantities?

Comment: @Chris thx for your time, I updated my question, you can see the model now thx

Comment: I posted an answer. That will help with displaying the correct value, but you will need  to figure out a different naming if you want to 2 way bind the inputs still so they can be edited retroactively.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @laziale?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using FormBuilder and FormControls in Angular, but here's something that might Work

COMPONENT TS

```js
model = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    quantities: [],
};

newQuantity = {
    name: '',
    price: ''
};

constuctor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

addNewQuantity() {
    this.model.quantities.push(this.newQuantity);
    this.newQuantity = {
        name: '',
        price: ''
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newQuantity.name" name="quantityname" placeholder="Enter Quantity" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newQuantity.price" name="quantityprice" placeholder="Enter Price" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>

<button (click)="addNewQuantity()">Add Quantity</button>

<div *ngFor="let quantity of model.quantities">
    <div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Quantity:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.name" name="quantityname" placeholder="Enter Quantity" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group kt-form__group row">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="quantity.price" name="quantityprice" placeholder="Enter Price" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
```

Comment: `ngModel` is there for a reason, it's not compulsory to use reactive forms everytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Took me a second. 
This info/answer is based off your other question that seems to relate to this same code: [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826569/angular-viewmodels-and-usage-in-components/57828221#57828221)

The reason for the list of quantities being the same is because you have an object called quantity accessible to the entire view via this declaration:

```
quantity: any = {
    price: '',
    name: ''
}
```

So in a view if you have the `([ngModel])=quantity.name` or `([ngModel])=quantity.price` it will be bound to the values in quantity. This is problematic because you are setting the value `quantity.name` in the addNewQuantity function.

```
addNewQuantity() {
    if (this.newQuantity) {
        this.quantity.name = this.newQuantity;
        this.model.quantity.push(this.quantity);
        this.newQuantity = '';
    }
}
```

So any template that is set with `([ngModel])=quantity.name` will now have the value set in the previous function.

A better implementation is to have a `newQuantityObject` and an object that has an array property that stores each newly added quantity. Then you don't need any new classes to implement. For example:

```
newQuantity = {
    price: '',
    name: ''
};

model: any = {
    TenantId: '',
    CustomFieldName: '',
    quantities: []
};


addNewQuantity() {
    if (this.newQuantity.price !== '' && this.newQuantity.name !== '') {
        this.model.quantities.push(this.newQuantity);
        newQuantity = {
            price: '',
            name: ''
        };
    }
}
```

Then you could display the list of quantity objects in a view like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let quantity of model.quantities; let i=index;" >
    <input type="text" value="{{quantity.name}}" [(ngModel)]="model.quantities[i].name" />
    <input type="text" value="{{quantity.price}}" [(ngModel)]="model.quantities[i].price"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what **PriceGridQuantity()** is doing but, You are adding same object reference each time that's why you are get same value in each quantity.

your code should look like this

```
addNewQuantity() {
if (this.newQuantity) {
let quantity = new PriceGridQuantity();
quantity.name = this.newQuantity;
this.model.quantities.push({name:this.newQuantity,price:quantity.price});
this.newQuantity = '';
}   
}
```

[click here to see exaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angula-form-dynamic-controls)